# Getting error "index out of range" while removing an element from the list

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to remove an element from my list but somehow seem to be getting an error of "list assignment index out of range" in temp[index2] assignment line. Below is my code.

```
  def remove(self, target_item):
    if self.count == 0:
        print("list is empty")
    else:
        index1 = 0
        index2 = 0
        temp = []
        while index1 < self.count:
            if self.str_list[index1] != target_item:
                temp[index2] = self.str_list[index1]
            else:
                self.count -= 1
        index = 0
        while index < self.count:
            self.str_list[index] = temp.index
```

Can someone explain as to why I am getting this error and how I can rectify this?

PS: I cant use any inbuilt list methods.

Comment: `temp` is an empty list. Try `temp.append(...)` or `temp = self..` it should solve the problem

Comment: cant use .append()

Comment: You're already using inbuilt methods. `[ ]` is an inbuilt method.

Comment: `temp` is an empty list going into the `while` loop, `index2 = 0`. You cannot  take the `0`th index of an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to modify `self.str_list` inplace ? Just build a new filtered list:

```
def remove(self, target_item):
    self.str_list = [item for item in self.str_list if item != target_item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `temp` list is initialized as empty. One way to fix this is to add condition to `if` statement or to initialize non-empty list.

```
if len(temp) > 0 and self.str_list[index1] != target_item:
    temp[index2] = self.str_list[index1]
```